# Post request using Python urllib

Tags: python, http, urllib

I'm making a request to an api using python3 urllib. This is my code,

```
headers = {}
    headers['Content-Type']='application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
    #headers['X-Csrf-Token']= {'mode: cors'}
    req = urllib.request.Request(url=URL, headers=headers, method='POST')
    res = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
    print(res.read())
```

I get the following response,

```
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 415: Unsupported Media Type
```

The API endpoint is working fine and I've tested it with Postman. This is the equivalent javascript code which gets the job done,

```
return fetch(url, { credentials : 'include', method: 'post'})
```

So I'm assuming I've to find a way to add credentials to the header. Can I do a credentials include parallel in Python or do I have to fetch the specific cookie and set it in the request. Any help appreciated.

Comment: every API can be different. Wecan't help without url do API.

Answer (score 0):

The error 415 indicates an issue with 'Content-type'.
'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' does not have any parameters.

https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/iana.html#application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Regarding fetch()'s "credentials", you would need the ability to maintain a session (sending cookies as required).
It is much easier with the requests library's Session

http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#session-objects